# How to select date from Telerik (kendo) date picker

Tags: selenium-webdriver, kendo-ui, datepicker, katalon-studio

I am having problem selecting a specific day in the pickDay() method. When I specify 4, it keeps selecting 1. When println date[DAY_OF_MONTH] it prints out 4.

I'm calling it with this keyword :-

> CustomKeywords.'custom.keywords.RadDatePicker.pickDate'('Object
>   Repository/Telerik/RadDateLightWeightPage/img_CalendarPopupButton',
>   '06/04/2019')

```
class RadDatePicker {

  Date date;
  String obj;

  RadDatePicker() {
  }

  RadDatePicker(String object, String input_date) {
    this.obj = object;
    date = new Date().parse("MM/dd/yyyy", input_date)
   }

  def openCalendar() {...}

  def displayMonth() {...}

  def displayYear() {...}

  def displayDate() {
    return new Date().parse("MMM/yyyy", displayMonth() + "/" + displayYear())
  }

  def pickYear(){...}

  def pickMonth(){...}

  def pickDay() {
    println date[DAY_OF_MONTH]
    WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Telerik/RadDateLightWeightPage/a_dayPicker', [('day') : date[DAY_OF_MONTH]]))
  }

  def pickDate() {
    pickYear()
    pickMonth()
    pickDay()
  }

  @Keyword
  def pickDate(String obj, String date) {
    def pick = new RadDatePicker(obj, date)
    pick.openCalendar()
    pick.pickDate()
  }
}
```

Here is the calendar and the HTML

[calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGcbI.png)
[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw1oz.png)

Comment: Show us how `'Object Repository/Telerik/RadDateLightWeightPage/a_dayPicker'` is defined.

Comment: //*[(text() = '1' or .= '1' is the selected locator

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around it by implementing WebDriver and looking for the specific xpath that contained the day I was looking for, here's the code

```
def pickDay() {

  WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver();;
  WebElement datepicker = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_cphContent_RadDatePicker1_calendar_Top']"));
  datepicker.findElement(By.xpath("//*[(text()=" + date[DAY_OF_MONTH] + ")]")).click();

}
```